# CircuiTikz - Proper Labeling in narrow circuits

Tags: circuitikz

I aim to create a rather wide circuit, but have a problem of proper labeling my components. Is there a way to put those labels in the narrow free spaces?

```
\begin{circuitikz}[]
    \draw (0,0) to[isource, l=$i_0$] (0,2) -- (1.5,2) to[R, l_=$G_S$] (1.5,0) -- (0,0);
    \draw (1.5,0) ++(1,1) node[draw,rounded corners=5pt,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=3cm] (box) {};
    \draw (1.5,0) -- (2,0);
    \draw (1.5,2) -- (2,2);
    \draw (3,0) -- (5,0);
    \draw (3,2) -- (5,2);
    \draw (3.5,2) to[C, l_=$C_1$] (3.5,0);
    \draw (4.5,2) to[R, l_=$jB_1$] (4.5,0);
\end{circuitikz}
```

The circuit looks like this:
[image]

Imagine that part repeating like 5 more times. In order to fit it all in one line I have to work rather space efficient... If any of you could assist me I would be very greatful :)

Have a nice day!

Comment: Welcome. // Please always provide code, which compiles. Yours misses a few lines ...

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few ways to do it.

The standard way, as described in section 5.1.1, is to use `label distance = 3mm` or so. However, this doesn't work out here (teal C1).

As `circuitikz` is built on `Tikz` you still can use its concepts. See below two inserted nodes, one wrt the upper (first) coordinate (red), and to the lower (second) coordinate (blue).

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
 \begin{circuitikz}[]
    \draw (0,0) to[isource, l=$i_0$] (0,2) -- (1.5,2) to[R, l_=$G_S$] (1.5,0) -- (0,0);
    \draw (1.5,0) ++(1,1) node[draw,rounded corners=5pt,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=3cm] (box) {};
    \draw (1.5,0) -- (2,0);
    \draw (1.5,2) -- (2,2);
    \draw (3,0) -- (5,0);
    \draw (3,2) -- (5,2);
    \draw (3.5,2) node[yshift=5mm,red]{$C_1$} 
                    to[C, l_=$C_1$, label distance=3mm,teal] (3.5,0);
    \draw (4.5,2) to[R, l_=$jB_1$] (4.5,0) node[yshift=-5mm,blue]{$R_1$};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, in this case I would go the red or blue thing --- just manually put every label below or above the component (also the ones that in principle would fit, for coherence)

Answer (score 2):

Every label is actually a separate node, and nodes can be placed manually pretty much anywhere.

One warning, the `to` command rotates the nodes which moves the node anchors accordingly.  See section 3.1.1 for the anchor names and definitions.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[every node/.style={font=\footnotesize}]
    \draw (0,0) to[isource, l=$i_0$] (0,2) -- (1.5,2) to[R, l_=$G_S$] (1.5,0) -- (0,0);
    \draw (1.5,0) ++(1,1) node[draw,rounded corners=5pt,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=3cm] (box) {};
    \draw (1.5,0) -- (2,0);
    \draw (1.5,2) -- (2,2);
    \draw (3,0) -- (5,0);
    \draw (3,2) -- (5,2);
    \draw (3.5,2) to[C, n=C1] (3.5,0);
      \node[above left] at (C1.west) {$C_1$};
    \draw (4.5,2) to[R, n=B1] (4.5,0);
      \node[left] at (B1.west) {$jB_1$};
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]